# Concatenation of multiple file in Qlikview

Tags: qlikview

Is that possible in qlikview to concatenate multiple files from different paths.

Suppose, i am loading multiple files with a path and want to concatenate multiple files which have same number and name of columns as first path's file. So, my question is how can i do that.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried to attempt this yourself?  Where is your script?

Answer (score 5):

When you say "load a file", I am assuming you mean that you are loading the contents into a table, as you would an QVD, XML, or Excel file.

If this is the case, if the columns are identical in each load, QlikView will attempt to concatenate them by default if they are loaded in sequence.

Otherwise, name your first table, such as `TableName:`, then preface the following loads of other files with `concatenate(TableName)`.

Ex:

```
TableName:
LOAD Col1, Col2
from [file.qvd];

CONCATENATE(TableName)
LOAD Col1, Col2
from [file2.qvd];
```

Note: As I mentioned above, since these are in sequence and have identically named columns, QlikView will attempt to autoconcatenate them in my example, so the `CONCATENATE` line, though still functional, is not required.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add example how to do it if there is dynamic amount of files in multiple directories with some name:

```
SUB LoadFromFolder (RootDir)
    TRACE Loading data ...;
    TRACE Directory: $(RootDir);
    TRACE ;

    FOR Each FoundFile in FileList(RootDir & '\FileName.xml')
        TRACE Loading data from '$(FoundFile)' ...;
        Data:
        LOAD Prop1,
            Prop2,
            Prop3
        From [$(FoundFile)] (XmlSimple, Table is [XmlRoot/XmlTag]);
        TRACE Loaded.;
    NEXT FoundFile

    FOR Each SubDirectory in DirList(RootDir & '\*' )
        CALL LoadFromFolder(SubDirectory);
    NEXT SubDirectory

    TRACE ;
END Sub

CALL LoadFromFolder ('C:\Path\To\Dir\WithoutslashAtTheEnd');
```

As Dickie already told, each time you load to "Data:", it will be added there.